# How to find the url of a service in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I have a local kubernetes cluster on my local docker desktop.

This is how my kubernetes service looks like when I do a `kubectl describe service`

```
Name:              helloworldsvc
Namespace:         test
Labels:            app=helloworldsvc
Annotations:       kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                     {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"helloworldsvc"},"name":"helloworldsvc","namespace":"test...
Selector:          app=helloworldapp
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.108.182.240
Port:              http  9111/TCP
TargetPort:        80/TCP
Endpoints:         10.1.0.28:80
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

This service is pointing to a deployment with a web app.

My question how to I find the url for this service?
I already tried http://localhost:9111/ and that did not work.

I verified that the pod that this service points to is up and running.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The service you have created is of type ClusterIP which is only accessible from inside the cluster. You have two ways to access it from your desktop:

1. Create a [nodeport](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) type service and then access it via `nodeip:nodeport`
2. Use Kubectl [port forward](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/) and then access it via `localhost:forwardedport`

Comment: Never use IP if you can use DNS, unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 179):

URL of service is in the below format:

```
<service-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:<service-port>
```

In your case it is:

```
helloworldsvc.test.svc.cluster.local:9111
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, is there a way to avoid the <namespace> in the URL?
I'm running a cron, than should make a request to the service in the same namespace.

Comment: if both services are in same namespace then just use service name. rest can be ignored

Comment: I have seen at some places this format `<pod-name>.<service-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:<service-port>` being used. Is this incorrect? If it's correct, when do we use this?

Comment: @RamPatra You can find the details on DNS queries for pod name under this section in Kubernetes documentation.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pods

Comment: just `helloworldsvc.test` is right?

Comment: that is also correct

Comment: So you guys managed to reach your service without a port-forward, locally?
Because on MacOS M1 I've tried all these approaches but none seem to work except for `kubectl port-forward`

Answer (score 30):

Get the service name: `kubectl get service -n test`

URL to a kubernetes service is **service-name.namespace.svc.cluster.local:service-port** where **cluster.local** is the kubernetes cluster name.

To get the cluster name: `kubectl config get-contexts | awk {'print $2'}`

**URL** to service in your case will be **helloworldsvc.test.svc.cluster.local:9111**

The way you are trying to do won't work as to make it available on your localhost you need to make the service available at [nodeport](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) or using [port-forward](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/#forward-a-local-port-to-a-port-on-the-pod) or using kubectl [proxy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#proxy).

However, if you want dont want a node port and to check if inside the container everything works fine then follow these steps to get inside the container if it has a shell.

`kubectl exec -it container-name -n its-namespace-name sh`

then do a

`curl localhost:80` or `curl helloworldsvc.test.svc.cluster.local:9111` or `curl 10.1.0.28:80`

but both curl commands will work only inside Kubernetes pod and not on your localhost machine.

To access on your host machine `kubectl port-forward svc/helloworldsvc 80:9111 -n test`

Answer (score 11):

The following `url` variations worked for me when in the same cluster and on the same namespace (namespace: `default`; though all but first should still work when services are on different namespaces):

```
http://helloworldsvc
http://helloworldsvc.default
http://helloworldsvc.default.svc
http://helloworldsvc.default.svc.cluster.local
http://helloworldsvc.default.svc.cluster.local:80
```

//

```
using HttpClient client = new();
string result = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
```

Notes:

- I happen to be calling to and from an ASP.NET 6 application using `HttpClient`
- That client I think just sets port to 80 by default, so no `80` port needs to be explicitly set to work. But I did verify for all of these it can be added or removed from the url
- `http` only (not `https`, unless you configured it specially)
- namespace can only be omitted in the first case (i.e. when domain / 'authority' is just the service name alone). So `helloworldsvc.svc.cluster.local:80` fails with exception `"Name or service not known (helloworldsvc.svc.cluster.local:80)"`

Answer (score 5):

If you are working with `minikube` , you can run the code below

```
minikube service --all
```

[image]

for specific service

```
minikube service service-name --url
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way to get the URL of service

Enter one pod through `kubectl exec`

```
kubectl exec -it podName -n namespace -- /bin/sh
```

Then execute `nslookup IP of service` such as `172.20.2.213` in the pod

```
/ # nslookup 172.20.2.213
nslookup: can't resolve '(null)': Name does not resolve

Name:      172.20.2.213
Address 1: 172.20.2.213 172-20-2-213.servicename.namespace.svc.cluster.local
```

Or execute `nslookup IP of serviceName` in the pod

```
/ # nslookup servicename
nslookup: can't resolve '(null)': Name does not resolve

Name:      172.20.2.213
Address 1: 172.20.2.213 172-20-2-213.servicename.namespace.svc.cluster.local
```

Now the service URL is `servicename.namespace.svc.cluster.local` attached with the service port after removing IP for the output of `nslookup`.

Answer (score 0):

just issue kubectl get all
That will give you something similar to this

[image]

Paste it in the browser

Answer (score -1):

Usually docker-based containers that would be run in K8s environments are stripped off any excessive tools, but if you enter your pod:

```
kubectl exec -it <pod-name> -n <namespace> -- /bin/sh
```

and after that use dnsdomainname like so:

```
kafka-0:/$ dnsdomainname
kafka-headless.kafka.svc.cluster.local
```